# Proper configuration of proxy for deegree

Tags: deegree

I am successfully running deegree 3.4.3 in 
Apache Tomcat/9.0.14 on windows 10.

However, the imports are not working. It is unclear what I should be doing to setup the proxy info. I run a localhost proxy which sets up all the information for the corporate host. Applications that look for http_proxy environment variable can use: http://localhost:3128  (There is a local service at port 3128 that adds all the credentials and forwards http/s requests to the company proxy).

Here is what the default is, but using that will allow me to connect to repo.deegree.org

`<ProxyHost>http://proxy.deegree.org</ProxyHost>
  <ProxyPort>8000</ProxyPort>
  <ProxyUser>deegree</ProxyUser>
  <ProxyPassword>pwd</ProxyPassword>
  <NonProxyHosts>127.0.0.1|localhost</NonProxyHosts>`

I have tried techniques that usually work for other programs here:

`<ProxyHost>http://localhost</ProxyHost>
  <ProxyPort>3128</ProxyPort>
  <ProxyUser></ProxyUser>
  <ProxyPassword></ProxyPassword>
  <NonProxyHosts>127.0.0.1|localhost</NonProxyHosts>`

Answer (score 1):

Please try the same configuration with deegree release version 3.4.7 or newer. Download from https://www.deegree.org/download/
This release includes the following fix "Fix incomplete implementation of proxy authentication" - https://github.com/deegree/deegree3/pull/987